# Azure Data Studio connection issue

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu, azure-data-studio

Cannot connect to mssql localhost instance via Azure Data Studio. Get: 'login failed for user sa'.

In the same time I'm able to successfully connect via terminal: `mssql -u sa -p myPassword`

mssql is in docker with status up

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=myPassword" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -h sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

os: ubuntu 20.04

firewal is off

I'm sure that pwd is correct, as I can connect to mssql via terminal. Is it Azure settings? Or ubuntu?
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You don't have closed the **"** on command after the password ` -e "SA_PASSWORD=myPassword <missing "> -p 1433:1433`

Comment: Thank you, Max! Actually I have closed missing quotes, and issue still keep reproducing

Comment: Check that between the localhost and 1433 (on Server field) there is a comma and SINGLE space. Check the `Advanced` button maybe there is encryption or other stuff enabled.

Comment: The reason was in special character in pwd ))

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to sql instance via Azure Data Studio after change the password. I was using special characters (@, #, $) that might have caused the problem.
After altering password that doesnt iclude special characters it starts working!